# Issue with "formula" to dynamically import .csv data to table (Power Query)

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a script that imports certain `.csv` data, filters it and draws a graph from it. So far so good. Instead of using a static file I want to make it dynamic, I want to choose a file from the filemanger and import it as a table.

First I recorded a macro to see what happens (see macro2), then I wrote some code to open a file manger and create a table out of it (see macro TestImport). I keep getting an error at this line

```
Filename, Formula:= _ "let" & Chr
```

I think the problem is something with the header names-types. Is there a way to just give the delimiter and name as formula and let excel figure out the rest?

Macro "FileNameNoExtensionFromPath" is a macro to create a query which works, but I can't convert it to a table. I added the code, an example of the csv file, as well as a picture of how it looks when using a static path. Is there someone who can help me out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="48 04 AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results", _
        Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Bron = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\sebastiaan\AppData\Local\KUKA\KUKA Sim Utilities PC 3.1\AutoOptimizePTP_TestFile_creationExcel\48.04 AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results.csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=8, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Headers met verhoogd niveau"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Bron, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & _
        "#""Type gewijzigd"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Headers met verhoogd niveau"",{{""INDEX"", Int64.Type}, {""CYCLETIME"", Int64.Type}, {""X"", Int64.Type}, {""Y"", Int64.Type}, {""Z"", type text}, {""PTP NAME"", Int64.Type}, {""AXIS"", Int64.Type}, {""DEGREES"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Type gewijzigd"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""48 04 AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results"";Extended Properties=""" _
        , """"), Destination:=Range("$A$4")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [48 04 AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "_48_04_AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub


Sub TestImport()

    Dim importPathVar As Variant
    Dim Filename As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.csv", 1
        If .Show = True Then
            importPathVar = .SelectedItems(1)
            Filename = Dir(importPathVar)
            MsgBox Filename
        Else
            MsgBox "You pressed Cancel"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End With


    Filename = FileNameNoExtensionFromPath(importPathVar)

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:= _
        Filename, Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & importPathVar & """),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=8, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Headers met verhoogd niveau"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Bron, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    " & _
        "#""Type gewijzigd"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Headers met verhoogd niveau"",{{""INDEX"", Int64.Type}, {""CYCLETIME"", Int64.Type}, {""X"", Int64.Type}, {""Y"", Int64.Type}, {""Z"", type text}, {""PTP NAME"", Int64.Type}, {""AXIS"", Int64.Type}, {""DEGREES"", Int64.Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Type gewijzigd"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location= " & Filename & ";Extended Proper" _
        , "ties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT * FROM [" & Filename & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = Filename
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
End Sub


Function FileNameNoExtensionFromPath(ByVal strFullPath As String) As String

    Dim intStartLoc As Integer
    Dim intEndLoc As Integer
    Dim intLength As Integer

    intStartLoc = Len(strFullPath) - (Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "\") - 1)
    intEndLoc = Len(strFullPath) - (Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "."))
    intLength = intEndLoc - intStartLoc

    FileNameNoExtensionFromPath = Mid(strFullPath, intStartLoc, intLength)

End Function







Sub importTable()

Dim myConnection As WorkbookConnection
Dim mFormula As String
mFormula = _
"let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\sebastiaan\AppData\Local\KUKA\KUKA Sim Utilities PC 3.1\AutoOptimizePTP_TestFile_creationExcel\48.04 AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results.csv""),null,""#(tab)"",null,1252) in Source"
query2 = ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add("query1", mFormula)

End Sub
```

Comment: You are getting an error in `& "" &` , if you want to add `"` inside a String you can use `Chr(34)`

Comment: thanks for your reply! I wil try that out, is there a way to leave the headers and types out of the formula an let excel figure it out himself?

Comment: Or you could use `& """" & ` -- a pair of double-quotes within a string literal is translated into one double-quote.